# jQuery object does not support this property or method

Tags: jquery

I have a code like this:

```
$(function() {
if ($("div#ProductDetail_ProductDetails_div2 table tbody tr").text().trim() == '') {
    $("div#ProductDetail_ProductDetails_div2").css("border", "0px");
    $("div#ProductDetail_ProductDetails_div").css({'border-bottom-left-radius' : '5px', '-moz-border-bottom-left-radius' : '5px', '-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius' : '5px', 'border-bottom-right-radius' : '5px', '-moz-border-bottom-right-radius' : '5px', '-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius' : '5px'});
}
});
```

Basically, it says if there is no content nested inside the `<tr>` , run some CSS modifications...

However, in IE8's debug console it says on this line `if ($("div#ProductDetail_ProductDetails_div2 table tbody tr").text().trim() == '') {` ***"object does not support this property or method"*** I have no clue what that means.

This is causing some problems with the other jQuery on the site. I know that when I comment it out, the site works perfectly. Can anybody tell me what's wrong the code that making IE complain? Thanks.

Comment: It means exactly what it says. Question is _which_ property or method is not supported. So it happens that I simply know the answer, but you really should learn to debug such trivial issues yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jquery trim function is like this

```
jQuery.trim( str )
```

and you probably need to get the td text value to compare.

Change it like this

```
if ($.trim($("div#ProductDetail_ProductDetails_div2 table tbody tr td:first").text())=="")
{
 //  Rest of the code
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: He's right. I didn't look closely at his code. Good call Shyju. +1

Comment: There's no `<td>`, that's why the `.trim()` is there in the first place